# Flow - When a file is created in SharePoint (spreadsheet) get rows and paste them in a master spreadsheet

Tags: power-automate

I have a SharePoint folder where only spreadsheets are uploaded. I need to extract data from one of the tables (Table1) and paste that in a different spreadsheet.

I'm stuck as to how to extract the rows from the spreadsheets as soon as these are uploaded:

[image]

This is the error I'm getting, my test spreadsheet does have a table created called "Table1".

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the dynamic content to make reference to a file on SharePoint has a bug that devs need to work on. For the time being the workaround is using OneDrive:

[image]